# Change animation speed of a 3D model

Tags: c#, unity, animation

I am working on a small simulator. There is a 3D character on the screen and it randomly plays an animation (I used `animation.PlayQueued(...)` command inside a `for` loop).
Now I have added a slider ( `GUI.VerticalSlider` ) on screen. I want to change the speed of all playing animations of 3D character when change the value of slider.

I know to use `animation["animationNane"].speed=xx;` but my problem is I have to pass the parameter of animation name that I want to change the speed . but actually I don't want to change the speed of specific animation clip. I want to change the speed of whatever the animation running in my 3d character. How can I change the speed of whatever animation is playing?

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of it, you want to change the speed of any animation playing. So, essentially, you want to change the speed of all playable animations. The `Animation` class inherits from `IEnumerable`, so you can iterate through all clips via a `foreach` loop.

C#:

```
foreach (AnimationState state in animation) {
    state.speed = 0.5F;
}
```

Unityscript (Pragma Strict):

```
for (var state : AnimationState in animation) {
    state.speed = 0.5;
}
```

The above will cause all the clips within the `animation` object to play at half speed. You can then change the speed back, or to whatever, whenever you need to.

[Unity Script Reference - Animation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation.html)

[Unity Script Reference - Animation Scripting (Legacy)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/AnimationScripting40.html)